# $M$ projective and finitely generated implies $Hom_R(M,R)$ is projective and finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated, projective-module, free-modules

I'm trying to prove that if $M$ is a left $R$-module projective and finitely generated, then $Hom_R(M,R)$ is a right $R$-module projective and finitely generated. I've seen comments where they use finite rank, but i cannot use that :(
Any hint?

Comment: No, i just have the basics equivalences of being proyective

Comment: What equivalences of being pro**j**ective did you see?